# Phone-Gap Claims Authentication against SharePoint in Office365 fails, probably because of HTTPOnly flag in cookie

Tags: web-services, jquery, claims-based-auth, office-365, rest

I am coding an application using [Phone Gap](http://phonegap.com/) to connect to a Sharepoint in Office365.

I need to use the REST services in Sharepoint Office 365 to add items to a list, but before that I need to authenticat

This is the javascript code I use to authenticate:

```
    $.ajax({
        'url': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf',
        dataType: 'text',
        type:'POST',
        'data': '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action><a:MessageID>urn:uuid:40c1407d-b2a4-4e05-8248-8a92b71102b6</a:MessageID><a:ReplyTo><a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address></a:ReplyTo><a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</a:To><o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><u:Timestamp u:Id="_0"><u:Created>2012-07-26T16:13:00.622Z</u:Created><u:Expires>2012-07-26T16:18:00.622Z</u:Expires></u:Timestamp><o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-69882db9-2d6b-45d3-b016-c2156cb6c01d-1"><o:Username>admin@somethingonline.onmicrosoft.com</o:Username><o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">******</o:Password></o:UsernameToken></o:Security></s:Header><s:Body><t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust"><wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"><a:EndpointReference><a:Address>https://somethingonline.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0</a:Address></a:EndpointReference></wsp:AppliesTo><t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType><t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType><t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType></t:RequestSecurityToken></s:Body></s:Envelope>',
        headers: {
            Accept : "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"
        },
        success: function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log('done in login ');
            console.log('result '+result);
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( result );
            console.log("xmlDoc:"+xmlDoc);
            var xml = $( xmlDoc )
            console.log("xml:"+xml);
            var binToken= xml.find( "wsse\\:BinarySecurityToken" ).text();
            console.log("Binary Token:"+binToken);

            //  alert(  localStorage.getItem('BinaryToken') );
            wsignin(binToken);
        },
        error:function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown+'error login:' + jqXHR.responseText);
        },
        complete:function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log('login completed ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
```

Which basically sends an `<s:Envelope>` requesting authentication.

This sends an XML with a `<wsse:BinarySecurityToken>` which we then use to actually authenticate:

```
function wsignin(token){
    // alert(  token );
    console.log('start wsignin' );
    console.log('wsignin token:'+token );
    $.ajax({
        'url': 'https://somethingonline.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0',
        dataType: 'text',
        type:'POST',
        'data':token,
        headers: {
            Accept : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        success: function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log('done wsignin ' + result);
            // alert( result  );
        },
        error:function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log('error wsignin:' + jqXHR.responseText);
        },
        complete:function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log('complete wsignin ' + textStatus);

        }
    });
    console.log('end wsignin' );
}
```

All this works perfectly with Explorer 9 (using  `jQuery.support.cors = true;`) but, the exact same code, with Phone Gap, instead of returning in the result the html of the main page **inside** `https://somethingonline.sharepoint.com/` it returns the Office365 login page.

What can I do? What am I doing wrong? Is there some other way to authenticate?

Update: Reading on MSDN found this:

> SharePoint Online Authentication Cookies
>
> An important aspect of this process, and the one that makes it
>   difficult but not impossible to use remote authentication for
>   SharePoint Online in client-side applications, is that the FedAuth
>   cookies are **written with an HTTPOnly flag**. This flag is designed to
>   prevent cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks. In a cross-site scripting
>   attack, a malicious user injects script onto a page that transmits or
>   uses cookies that are available on the current page for some nefarious
>   purpose. The HTTPOnly flag on the cookie prevents Internet Explorer
>   from allowing access to the cookie from client-side script. The
>   Microsoft .NET Framework observes the HTTPOnly flag also, **making it
>   impossible to directly retrieve the cookie from the .NET Framework
>   object model.**

Maybe this means... that integration with Sharepoint Online in Office365 ¿is plain impossible?

Comment: Did you get this to work? I'm looking into the same issue at the moment.

Comment: No, it still does not work

Comment: Did you guys come up with a solution to this? I am in the same boat, lol. Cheers

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).

Comment: @Chunkyfeather no, so far it does not work, so we had to abandon PhoneGap

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting topic.

The integration with Office 365 and SharePoint Online is **possible**. See the detailed instructions and examples for [.NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2011/05/14/part-2-headless-authentication-with-sharepoint-online-and-the-client-side-object-model.aspx), [.NET again](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-to-do-active-authentication-to-Office-365-and-SharePoint-Online.aspx), [node.js](http://allthatjs.com/2012/03/28/remote-authentication-in-sharepoint-online/), [python](https://gist.github.com/2272889).

I have tested it in javascript, in node.js and it works. There all you need to do is to [install sharepoint node package](http://allthatjs.com/2012/03/29/node-js-meet-sharepoint/). The logic is the same as in .NET or python or Java, the same as you do in your code:

1. Send a SAML code to STS (Security Token Service) with username,
   password and endpoint.
2. Send the token you've got to the login page. Capture the cookies
   `rtFA` and `FedAuth`
3. Append these two cookies as request headers in every request to the
   sharepoint online site.

[I tried](https://github.com/mirontoli/sp-lend-id/tree/master/purneske/android/assets/www/poc) your solution (which I modified a little bit). **Requesting the token works and the wsignin works perfectly**.

The only thing that doesn't work are the `rtFA` and `FedAuth` cookies. I can't get them in a XMLHttpRequest in the PhoneGap WebView (which is a kind of a mobile browser). So these cookies aren't sent automatically, and you can't get them in a webview with javascript. You have to create some additional server layer to handle authentication and data retrieving.

UPDATE: The only "Set-Cookie" I get in the XMLHttpResponse from wssignin page is **MSPOK**:

> set-cookie:
>   MSPOK=$uuid-3367547c-f7aa-4054-aa34-fdf0de2ae83d$uuid-445d329f-6466-42f4-b1c7-5f417fa528af$uuid-2a4bba00-1e7b-494d-af4d-19fb7c2646ff$uuid-1bfdab84-eacb-4908-88df-d7e7e927749e;domain=login.microsoftonline.com;path=/;version=1

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I know it works with .NET, IE9, and node.js (not tried phython, no need) **but** the thing is that it does **not** work with [Phone-Gap](http://phonegap.com/). And my question is explicitly about doing it with **Phone-Gap**

Comment: I know. I said about node and python just to be complete. I tested this in PhoneGap and answered what I found. Hopefully we can find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you resolved your problem yet, but I would try to set the UserAgent header inside your requests to a valid browser User Agent, for example:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
```

It should help.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I do not see why it should... this problem is derived from the fact that Office365 uses FedAuth cookies that are written with an HTTPOnly flag, regardless of the User Agent (and **PhoneGap** seems unable to deal with those)